# IIS https non-www redirect to https www

Tags: redirect, https

My IIS server does not redirect when using https with non-www. What I would like to achieve is to redirect https://xyzdomain.com to https://www.xyzdomain.com.

http://xyzdomain.com and **http://www.xyzdomain.com are redirected correctly to https://www.xyzdomain.com.

For the moment the code looks as follows:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.xyzdomain\.ro$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.xyzdomain.ro/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Thank you in advance,
TrQ

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  In other words, please show what you have tried so far and explain what happens that isn't what you would expect.